Shift vehicles continuously running wear out too quickly
Does anyone know if there are any studies/reports that show the damages that are caused by shift vehicles being run 24 hours a day? I am hoping to compile enough data to justify buying two more vehicles so we can let day shift vehicles rest at night/night shift vehicles rest during the day.  Currently we run two vehicles 24 hours a day and they are always in need of repair from what I assume are the effects of continuously running slow (idle-30 mph max).

What does it mean for a vehicle to "rest"? How would that affect the wear and tear when it is working? If you do that, then they will spend more time idling with a cold engine at the start of a shift, which isn't good. Another possible problem is skipping the service schedule, if you don't have enough vehicles to cover the "down time" of those being serviced, possibly resulting in 'always in need of repair'.
